# Combining dateparts to create new datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, combinations, datepart

I am trying to create my own date by combining dateparts of different columns. My code is below:

```
CAST((datepart(yy,[FIRST_INSTALL_DATE]) 
     + '-'
     + datepart(mm,[INSTALL_DATE]) 
     + '-'
     + datepart(dd,[INSTALL_DATE])) as Datetime) AS [Install_Date],
```

(Where FIRST_INSTALL_DATE's value is 2014-01-01 and INSTALL_DATE's value is 1900-08-07.)

However, I get the output below where it is supposed to be **2014-08-07 00:00:00.000**

```
1905-08-07 00:00:00.000
```

I appreciate any idea. Thanks.

Comment: which sql server version?

Comment: What is the value of `FIRST_INSTALL_DATE` for the record in question which generated the data shown?

Comment: If 2012+ consider DateFromParts()

Comment: Version: SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you are trying to add numbers,

```
2014 +- 03 +- 02
```

You must convert every DATEPART to VARCHAR before to concat it.

```
CAST(DATEPART(YY, FIRST_INSTALL_DATE) AS varchar(10))
```

SQL-Server 2012

> ```
> DECLARE @FIRST_INSTALL_DATE datetime = '2016/01/01 00:00:00';
> DECLARE @INSTALL_DATE datetime = '2017/02/03 00:00:00';
>
>
> SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (datepart(yyyy, @FIRST_INSTALL_DATE), 
>                       datepart(MM,@INSTALL_DATE), 
>                       datepart(dd,@INSTALL_DATE)) AS InstallDate;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | InstallDate         |
> | :------------------ |
> | 03/02/2016 00:00:00 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b4193bb3ac8b2360c7572e3e86636c64)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ISO 8601 YYYYMMDD format when convert to Datetime

```
SELECT
CAST(
  CAST(datepart(yy,[FIRST_INSTALL_DATE]) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(datepart(mm,[INSTALL_DATE]) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(datepart(dd,[INSTALL_DATE]) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
AS DATETIME) AS [Install_Date],
```

Comment: I get an error called **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."**